# Partial declarations of '[WPFApplication].MainWindow' must not specify different base classes

Tags: wpf, telerik, interop, window, radwindow

I am working in a `WPF\Telerik Project. I have came across a very strange problem, that I can not use a work around, because of the inter-dependency of functionality.

My project has a auto log out functionality and for that I have to use this piece of code as shown below.

```
private void InitializeAutoLogoffFeature()
    {
        HwndSource windowSpecificOSMessageListener = HwndSource.FromHwnd(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
        windowSpecificOSMessageListener.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(CallBackMethod));
        LogOffHelper.LogOffTime = logOffTime;
        LogOffHelper.MakeAutoLogOffEvent += new MakeAutoLogOff(AutoLogOffHelper_MakeAutoLogOffEvent);
        LogOffHelper.StartAutoLogoffOption();

    }
```

in this `HwndSource windowSpecificOSMessageListener = HwndSource.FromHwnd(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);` line of code I have to pass the window(`this`).

So that the `[Window_Name]` window has to be implemented using `Window` since `WindowInteropHelper` constructor only accepts `Window` type.

But when I impliments as belows

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
```

I get a error,

```
Partial declarations of '[WPFApplication].MainWindow' must not specify different base classes
```

this `MainWindow` is not a `Window` its a `Telerik window`.

XML is shown below.

```
    <telerik:RadWindow x:Class="[WPFApplication].MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
        Header="POS" Height="820" Width="1280" 
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <telerik:RadWindow.Resources>
..
```

This is my App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="[WPFApplication].App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow"
         >

<Application.Resources>

</Application.Resources>
```

I also tried by using this code as well in `App.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        new MainWindow().Show();
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

How should I overcome this error?

Comment: I think you need to use the approach overriding `OnStartup` and *not* using `StartupUri` (see http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/wpf/window/radwindow-as-main-window.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `MainWindow` is a `RadWindow`, you need

```
public partial class MainWindow : RadWindow
```

because the class of your window in `XAML` and in `.cs` need to be identical:

```
<telerik:RadWindow x:Class="[WPFApplication].MainWindow" ...>
         ^^^^^^^^^
```

According to the posts in [this thread](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/window/show-in-taskbar.aspx), `RadWindow` uses a `Window` as container that can be accessed like that

```
var window = this.ParentOfType<Window>();
```

so you can use your `RadWindow` as `MainWindow` ([KB article](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/wpf/window/radwindow-as-main-window.aspx)) and pass a standard WPF window to the InteropHelper

Comment: Yes this is correct, but since I have to pass a `Window` type I can not implement `RadWindow`, do I have to change my implementation, or is there a work around. :(

Comment: OK that's another problem - maybe you should open a new question for that (Getting the Handle of a RadWindow).

Comment: @Diode I updated my answer so that both questions are answered :-) Hope this helps